# How many objects will be eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

So I've recently been to job interview and was asked the following question. *(Actually it was just a test writing, so I couldn't ask any questions)*

**At the end of the main method, how many objects will be eligible for garbage collection?**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            obj = new Object();
        }
        obj = null;
    }
}
```

**(A)  0**

**(B)  1**

**(C)  5**

I know it's 0 because at least one object (`obj`) will be garbage collected, but I also know that `obj` is not really the object, it's just a reference to it. So my answer was 5.

Is that correct? If not, then why?

Comment: wow.. too many bullets on single line.. btw 5 is right answer

Comment: its so easy man. It should be `Five`. but it must me mentioned at which line too??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer `5 is correct`.

Here total 5 number of objects are created through for loop and all of these will be eligible for garbage collection at the end of the method.

Answer (score 4):

Probably **0**,

The compiler might workout some optimisation and eliminate the entire loop and avoid creating the five objects created in the loop in the first place.

So if no compiler optimisation is going on,  5 objects are created inside the loop and their references is being overwritten in the variable `obj`, at the end variable will reference the last object which is being assigned to `null`.

Comment: Is that an option too? In what situations can a compiler decide to do that?

Comment: If the loop does nothing, the compiler might eliminate it.

Comment: Probably you are right, but still it depends on compiler and its run time optimization. +1

Comment: the constructor might still have some business logic which compiler cannot ignore.

Comment: I'm not sure this will be optimized. What if something happens in the constructor? Maybe because that's just a plain `Object` instance, but still I doubt nothing would happen. In any case, I guess the question was meant for showing understanding of the idea behind garbage collection and does not mean to take compiler optimizations into account

Comment: @Avi I hope that was the case.

Comment: @sidgate  what business logic in Object constructor?

Comment: @sidgate no they aren't the same, JIT does code analysis to know that.

Comment: @sidgate the compiler looks for "side effects" in its optimisation, "business logic" is a term that the compiler doesn't understand